# Dual Monitor in Dreamweaver

Tags: dreamweaver, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors (they are different sizes). I'm trying to view and edit the code (HTML, css, JavaScript) in one screen, and have the live/preview window at the second screen. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this. Do you have any suggestions?

**What I've tried:**

- Extending Dreamweaver's window then use split. It doesn't really work
  because the screens heights aren't the same size so in one screen
  Dreamweaver will be shorter
- Opening Window > Code Inspector. That doesn't work because you can
  only edit the HTML file, not the css or JavaScript file.

Comment: I sure hope dreamweaver isn't commonly used by programmers

Comment: I use it because I like the fact that it has live preview, as opposed to constantly reloading to see the results.

Comment: If you are just making changes in the view and not actually testing input you can use  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10" /> this will refresh your page every 10 seconds

Comment: I tried that, but then I will have to save it myself.